# What does the phrase "I broke the mold and tossed the clay" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was listening to a song and there was such a verse:

> My way or the highway – I’m one dimensional
> I broke the mold and tossed the clay, incomprehensible
> I’m the only - A rarity

I can't figure out what the phrase "I broke the mold and tossed the clay" mean in this context? I read that "to break the mold" means to do something in a completely new way. But what does it mean "to toss the clay"?

I'd be grateful for an explanation!

Comment: If the clay is thrown out (tossed), the mold cannot be remade.

Comment: The phrase could also mean that the person stopped pretending to be someone else to meet other people's expectations. These are beautiful lines by the way so I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you are the first and last of your kind, and it implies that this unique aspect of you, or whoever is the subject, is special and desireable.

I've heard it said where someone was talking about themselves, or perhaps a romantic partner, as being so good they're almost perfect.  And so, God decided it was his best work and couldn't be topped so he broke the mold that he used to make people from and threw away the stuff we're made of-clay.  Since he perfected that person, a copy would never measure up, and so his work is done.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! So, in this context "I broke the mold" is not an idiom as I thought before.

Comment: Yes, it's an idiom implying that there will never be another one like the thing or person in question.

Comment: I mean, when I tried googling for the phrase "break the mold", all dictionaries gave me basically only one meaning - to do something in a new way. However, the Wordnik dictionary offered one more - To make it impossible for an identical copy to be made. This is exactly what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: @KateBunting It's more common as "_They_ broke the mould when they made him/her" though don't you think? Also "tossed the clay" is not part of the idiom as I've heard it so that is genuine creativity.

Comment: @BoldBen - Yes, I typed the comment in haste and thought after logging out that I should have specified that it didn't include throwing away the clay. I meant that the idea of 'breaking the mould' was an idiom.

Comment: Interestingly to me is that when a potter creates a unique item from clay on a potter's wheel, the idiom is "throwing a pot" or "throwing the clay," which implies a clever double meaning: is the person saying they did away with the clay (i.e., all expectations) or that they created their own unique item with the raw materials they had been given?

Comment: When we break a mould used in metal casting, we are most often going to return the material to be ground up and used again. Casting moulds are generally made out of sand, so I think the songwriter used 'clay' because of a need for a rhyme for 'highway'. I think it is clear that he or she has not worked in a casting shop.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey do you want to say that in the song the clay is what the mold was made from?

Comment: Figured it would be like this how you think you're superior I have no clue. Good luck one day it will come back on you.